# Javascript code to change innerHTML value if textlength > 250

Tags: javascript

```
for(y=0;y<3;y++)
{
var Text = 0;
var TextLength = 0;
var Text = document.getElementsByClassName("Introduction")[y].innerHTML;
var TextLength = Text.length;

    if(TextLength > 250){
        document.getElementsByClassName("Read_More")[y].innerHTML = "Read More";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementsByClassName("Read_More")[y].innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

This code is meant to run twice, each time calculating the length/number of characters, in a 'p' whose class is "Introduction."

There are three of these, but since numbering begins from 0, and not 1, the code says "y<3." If the value of TextLength, which is the number of characters in 'p class="Introduction"', is greater that 250, the text in 'p class="Read_More"' shall be "Read More."

If it isn't, it shall remain empty. The number of 'p class="Introduction"' and 'p class="Read_More"' is the same, and it should the require condition be met in the former, the code will be executed in the corresponding latter element.

Although I have tried this code on online debuggers, where nothing wrong is detected, and on online web-designing tools, where it works as it is supposed to, once I try it on the browser, it does not work. I would be grateful if anyone here could help me out.

Comment: when you try it in the browser open the debugger tools and put a breakpoint in the code. (Chromes tools are the best) Then just step through and examine all the values.

Comment: It will be easier with a fiddle so we can try to see what's wrong, from here we can't know if you receive null in some point..

Comment: I don't see how this wouldn't work, however you could change your code slightly: for(y = 0; y < 3; y++)
{
var TextLength = document.getElementsByClassName("Introduction")[y].innerHTML.length;
    if(TextLength > 250){
        document.getElementsByClassName("Read_More")[y].innerHTML = "Read More";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementsByClassName("Read_More")[y].innerHTML = "";
    }
}

Comment: I tried changing .innerHTML to .innerHTML.length, but it didn't change anything.
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you mean this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var intros= document.getElementsByClassName("Introduction"),
      mores= document.getElementsByClassName("Read_More");
  for (var i = 0; i < intros.length; i++) {
    var text = intros[i].innerHTML;
    var textLength = text.length;
     mores[i].innerHTML=textLength>250?"Read More":"";
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="Introduction">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris magna ligula, sagittis at velit quis, laoreet rhoncus metus. Praesent ac aliquam enim, quis fringilla nunc. Proin eget viverra ligula, a blandit neque. Quisque finibus luctus elementum.</p><p class="Read_More"></p>
<hr />
<p class="Introduction">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris magna ligula, sagittis at velit quis, laoreet rhoncus metus. Praesent ac aliquam enim, quis fringilla nunc. Proin eget viverra ligula, a blandit neque. Quisque finibus luctus elementum. Donec sed.</p><p class="Read_More"></p>
<hr />
<p class="Introduction">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris magna ligula, sagittis at velit quis, laoreet rhoncus metus. Praesent ac aliquam enim, quis fringilla nunc. Proin eget viverra ligula, a blandit neque.</p><p class="Read_More"></p>
```

Comment: In fact, I just added window.onload = function(){} to my original code, and it works like a dream. Of course, the rest of the code is unchanged, but it works. Thank you, once again.

Comment: They existed, but the problem was that the JavaScript wasn't being run without the window.onload line.

Comment: That is what I meant. Running code after the object have rendered in the DOM